# How to install AMD Drivers correctly?

Tags: 12.04, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

I recently installed ATI Drivers from the Ubuntu repository but after the installation when I try to open ATI Catalyst Control Center. I get a message that ATI Drivers are not properly installed or there is a problem with the hardware.

Similar problem was faced by a friend of mine. On his laptop Mint worked smoothly but the drivers for ATI were not installed correctly
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really good community wiki on this which should help you on this site here

[Ask Ubuntu ATI Community Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

Ubuntu also have an easy to follow guide here

[Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

To start with you will have to purge the installation you have of all the ATI information by doing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

This will clean out any crudd that is left over/obsolete and then you can follow either of the guides above.